# GEN_SIZE_INVALID, details: The object size passed is too big for processing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

What does the following HttpResponse-Content actually mean when using autodesk-forge's webservice to copy a file-version via the resource "data/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/versions?copyFrom={ESCAPED_VERSION_ID}"?

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},
"errors":[{
"id":"3a6cb28b-6656-451c-acfb-1c68ddb24a45",
"status":"400",
"code":"ERR_BAD_INPUT",
"title":"The request has invalid header or body",
"detail":"GEN_SIZE_INVALID, details: The object size passed is too big for processing."
}]}
```

Is there a limit to the number of versions that can be referenced or anything like that?

Here's the payload with dummy values:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "versions",
    "relationships": {
      "refs": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink1}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink2}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink3}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink4}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink5}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink6}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink7}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink8}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink9}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink10}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink11}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink12}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink13}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink14}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink15}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink16}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink17}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink18}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink19}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink20}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink21}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink22}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink23}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "{{VersionURNforLink24}}",
            "meta": {
              "refType": "xrefs",
              "direction": "from",
              "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "data": {
                  "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the first time I see this error. Could you share your POST body and point out which API endpoint you're using?

Comment: @EasonKang I am afraid the comment size is too small to post the payload. To answer your question somewhat though: We are posting the payload described in https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-docs-setting-external-references-between-files-upload-linked-files against the resource "data/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/versions?copyFrom={ESCAPED_VERSION_ID}" referencing 24 other file-versions.

Comment: Ok, maybe added to your question body above. anyway ... I'm checking with our engineering team. Meanwhile, may I know the total size of your 24 other file versions?

Comment: And which folder are those files located in, `Plans` or `Project Files`?

Comment: If there is any information you cannot post publicly, you may contact `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` instead. It would be great that you can share the POST body you used to call the POST `data/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/versions?copyFrom={ESCAPED_VERSION_ID}`. if so, we can check the backend log for the possible root causes.

Comment: @EasonKang I have updated the question and will send the used resource and actual payload to the e-mail address you've provided. All file-versions reside in multiple subfolders below "Project Files". The version used as a source for copying is 1.74 MB in size while all 24 directly referenced files amount to about 38 MB.

Answer (score 0):

From all the data we've been able to gather so far: There is in fact a limit on how many files can be referenced directly, which seems to be **50**.
The reason it occurred in so many places for us when we didn't have any files referencing nearly that amount of other plans, was how the "CopyFrom"-functionality works.

**Example on how to reproduce the problem:**
Given "plan A" and "plan B" ("B" referencing "A"), upload both files and create their initial items/versions. Now do the following:
1.) re-upload "A" and create a new version.
2.) use "CopyFrom" on the latest version of "B" and define the reference to the latest version of "A".

Since "CopyFrom" adds references instead of replacing them, version #2 of "B" now holds two references. One towards the initial version #1 of "A" and one to the latest version of "A".
Repeat these steps enough times and you'll eventually run into this issue.

**Solution:**
Even though nothing except one reference has changed on "B", one needs to reupload the file defining all required references so version #N of "B" only references version #N of "A". (Be wary that this behaviour of course may change in the future!)